# Box2D and glut. Problems with framerate

Tags: c++, opengl, box2d, glut, frame-rate

I am having problems getting glutTimerFunc() to play nicely with box2d's world->step();

Here are the values I'm passing into them

```
glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
world->Step((1.0f/60.0f), 8, 6);
```

The problem with this is that with the timerFinc at 0 the graphics don't have time to render properly so my graphics become jumpy. If I pass any other value into timerFunc my graphics basically come to a standstill be it 1, 20 or any value in between. I also can't pass other values into world->step without things getting very messy.

Is there some way I can get the two to run together. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you have strict timing needs, such as for a game or physics simulation, you should not be using FreeGLUT at all. Try [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) instead. It allows you to manage the rendering loop manually, and thus, you have full control over timing.